# C++ Same Variable on Left and Right Side of Assignment

Tags: c++

Suppose that we have some object, such as `std::vector<int> foo`.

I know from reading the C++ docs on self-assignment that `foo = foo` (although weird) should technically be OK since classes in C++ are responsible for being self-assignment safe.

However, suppose that I also have some method `reverse()` that **does not** modify the input, but instead returns a **new** vector that is a reversed version of the given argument. I then perform:

`foo = reverse(foo);`

Would this be OK? I've gone down a pretty deep rabbit hole reading about sequence points and things like that, and TBH my brain is sort of fried now- could anybody offer a more straightforward explanation here? I know that `x = x + 5` where `x` is of type `int` is clearly fine, but I'm wondering how this changes when we're dealing with objects that allocate memory.

In addition, suppose that we had another method `reverseMutate()` that **does** mutate the input, and then returns that reversed (mutated) original vector back. I'm even less clear whether

`foo = reverseMutate(foo);`

is defined behavior.

Thank you so much for the help! I promise I've tried diving into the C++ docs, and I'm just looking for a more straightforward explanation that doesn't make my brain hurt...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes on both counts. Everything is safe.

```
foo = reverse(foo);
```

If `reverse` *doesn't* mutate `foo`, then it returns a completely unrelated vector, and *that* vector is assigned to `foo`. Those two steps happen in that order. The result of `reverse` must be fully known before `operator=` is ever called on `foo`, for the same reason that if we do `bar(baz(1))`, the `baz` call must completely terminate *before* `bar` is ever called.

```
foo = reverseMutate(foo);
```

This one is a little more exciting but is still fine. If `reverseMutate(foo)` mutates `foo` and then returns it (i.e. literally `return *this;` as a `std::vector<int>&`), then it behaves the same as

```
reverseMutate(foo);
foo = foo;
```

i.e. it's just self-assignment in disguise, and as you've already correctly pointed out, C++ classes are responsible for being able to handle this case.

Comment: Thank you! Much more straightforward to understand than sequence points :)

I was a bit nervous because of the "aliasing" behavior that Eigen demonstrates, but it seems like this is just a strange quirk of this library:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html

Comment: It looks like that `transpose` function returns some sort of view-like object, so assigning the view back to the original matrix tries to write overlapping memory. Basically, you're running into the exact same problem you'd run into if you'd done a [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) and the two pointers overlapped. It's definitely a quirk, I wouldn't say it's *bad* C++, especially since the quirk is well-documented, but it's atypical.